# Marking on HTML5 Meter/ProgressBar Tag Using Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to tag at various points using images/icons of varying sizes[image] on a HTML5 Meter. Now I can use a span tag to do that by placing it at various parts of the meter.

Is there another alternative to this? I was wondering if I could use the canvas element to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would definitely be easier with a canvas or WebGL.

Canvas example, assuming that `images` is an array of an object with the fields `image`, `x`, and `y`:

```
context.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 10); // Progressbar background. Alternatively, you could stroke it (draw a border).
context.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10); // Draw the current progress. I've hard coded it to 10% here.
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
    var a = images[i]; // I'm lazy
    context.fillRect(a.x - 1, 0, 2, a.y); // less code than stroking
    context.drawImage(a, a.x, a.y);
}
```